# Error 1004 "application defined or object defined error"

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to made a command button to automatically fill a table on a summary sheet by the user specifying a date and then the code will check through each sheet (which have identical tables and data on them) and copy rows with matching date entries into the summary table.

I keep getting a 1004 error at the line "tst=cells(x,A)" and it says it fails to record range. I have tried setting different variable types and specifying the location with "Worksheets(sheet).Range("Ax")" but that still doesn't work.

Any help to fix this issue or improve the code would be great thanks.

this is my code:

```
Private Sub UpTbl_Click()
UpTbl.FontSize = 8
  
' Variables
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim indSUM As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim Dte As Date
Dim tst As Date
Dim sheet As String
   
indSUM = 10
Dte = Worksheets("summary").Range("C4")
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    ' Begin the loop.
    For I = 3 To WS_Count
        sheet = Worksheets(I).Name
        ind = 5
        Worksheets(sheet).Activate
        
        
        For x = 6 To 900
        tst = Range("Ax")

             If Dte = tst Then
                Worksheets(sheet).Range("Ax:Jx").Copy
                Worksheets("SUMMARY").Range("NindSUM:WindSUM").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValue
                indSUM = indSUM + 1
                
            End If
            
        Next x
        
    Next I
    
  Sheets("SUMMARY").Activate
  End Sub
```

Comment: `tst = Range("Ax")` is Ax a named range?

Comment: `tst = Range("A" & x)` same with your other range that uses the variable `x`

Comment: Try `tst = Range("A" & x)`. Also change the rest of the code accordingly. Like in `Worksheets(sheet).Range("Ax:Jx").Copy` that will become `Worksheets(sheet).Range("A" & x & ":J" & x).Copy`.

Comment: for cells: `tst = cells(x,"A")` or better `tst = cells(x,1)`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to reference the variable `x` meaning you need:

```
tst = Range("A" & x)
```

---

To reference you larger range with variables you can use something like

```
With Worksheets(sheet)
     .Range(.Range("A" & x), .Range("J" & x))
End With
```

Comment: I know this could have been in comment but leave me alone, i'm trying to get to 14k

Comment: Upvoted for 14k

Comment: WHERE YOU AT CRANER

Comment: `.Cells(.Range("A" & x), .Range("J" & x))` should be `.Range(.Range("A" & x), .Range("J" & x))`,

Comment: there he is. hahaha. I'm rusty - nice to see you keeping me correct again :P

Comment: I was off trying to find the duplicate.  Decided not to close it as such since you answered.

Comment: @ScottCraner hero as always. I live in SQL world now but like to answer the occasional soft ball to not forget everything

Comment: I haven't got much experience with VBA, but I am wanting to take the date from the table column, in a variable (x) row, column A, and make it go through each row to compare to the input date. and run the statement if true.

Comment: Also if i run the code up to that point the date specified in the variable tst is 12:00am but the cell has a yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: @swiebe use `Range("....").Value2` to compare the date serial number. This bypasses the need to format dates for comparisons. (make this change to both date variables and change the variable type to long). You could also format the date but If I remember correctly, the format shouldn't matter

Comment: I need to start frequenting the sql world.  My job is more t-sql than excel now.